# Show that $ \int_0^\pi \cot(x)\arctan(\tanh\pi(\tan(x))) \mathrm{d}x=\pi \log(3)$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, closed-form

> Show that$$\int_0^\pi  \cot(x)\arctan(\tanh\pi(\tan(x))) \mathrm{d}x=\pi \log(3)$$

A friend sent me this problem. I managed to solve it but can we do it in other ways ?

Comment: If you're asking for different approaches to solve a task it's better to directly incorporate your own solution within your question instead of posting a separate answer. Sure, as a FAQ website posting a answer separately isn't that bad at all (as we then have a question and a corresponding answer) but tends to attract close-votes.

Comment: @mrtaurho I totally agree with you but still I dont see why these people down/close vote the problem. I still wonder, instead of close voting the problem, why dont they recommend the OP to do what they think needs to be done.

Comment: @AliShather Usually those users capable of voting to close maintain their own philosophy regarding casting close-votes. E.g., the question is only a problem stated without an own attempt included $\implies$ close vote. Explaining every single time why they cast a close vote is tedious and therefore not that many people tend to do so.

Comment: @mrtaurho then the policy of this site is the one to blame.

Answer (score 4):

I found general generalization for this problem
$$\mathrm{Let} \; \mathrm{I} \; = \; \int_0^\pi \cot(x)\arctan(\tanh\theta (\tan(x))) \mathrm{d}x$$

$$= \quad 2 \int_0^\infty \frac{\arctan(\tanh(\theta x))}{x(x^2+1)} \mathrm{d}x $$
$$ \mathrm{we\;know\;that}\;\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(\theta x )}{\cosh(x)} \mathrm{d}x = \frac{\pi}{2} \frac{1}{\cosh(\frac{\pi \theta}{2})} $$
So
$$ \; \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(\theta x )}{x \cosh(x)} \mathrm{d}x = 2 \arctan(\tanh(\theta \frac{\pi}{4})) $$
$$I = \quad 4 \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(a yx)}{y \cosh(y)x(x^2+1)} \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y \;=\; 2 \pi \int_0^\infty \frac{(1-e^{-ay})}{y \cosh(y)} \mathrm{d}y $$
where $a = \frac{4\theta}{\pi}$
$$ = 2\pi \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-xy}(1-e^{-ay})}{ \cosh(y)} \mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}x $$
$$ = \pi \int_0^\infty \psi\bigg(\frac{3}{4}+\frac{x}{4}\bigg)-\psi\bigg(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{x}{4}\bigg)-\psi \bigg(\frac{3+a}{4}+\frac{x}{4}\bigg)+\psi\bigg(\frac{1+a}{4}+\frac{x}{4}\bigg)\mathrm{d}x $$ 
$$= \quad \pi \log\Bigg(\frac{\Gamma(\frac{\theta }{\pi}+\frac{3}{4}) \Gamma(\frac{1}{4})}{\Gamma(\frac{\theta }{\pi}+\frac{1}{4}) \Gamma(\frac{3}{4})} \Bigg) $$
So when $\theta = \pi $
$$ \int_0^\pi \cot(x)\arctan(\tanh\pi (\tan(x))) \mathrm{d}x \; = \; \pi \log(3)$$